# PHP file uploads - whole file in memory?

Tags: php, file-upload

How does PHP treat uploaded files?
If a user uploads a file(POST), what happens with the file before it's written to a temporary location on the disk? Is it loaded and reconstructed in memory as a whole, and when it's done it's moved to disk, or is it treated like a byte stream and pieces of it are written to disk when a buffer becomes full?

Couldn't seem to find a proper answer to this question.

Comment: I assume it would all be loaded into memory because the file gets reconstructed when its in /tmp

Comment: That's what I initially thought, but then if you would allow large files to be uploaded, you would also need very large amounts of memory, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Well thats true however when its being uploaded it also writes data to the file and cleans up the memory a bit. So If you send one MB to the server it gets loaded into a block then written to the file then the next MB overrides that same block. Cleaning up memory as it goes. (I am sorry for my grammar. I am off today)

Comment: That is basically what I asked. So it doesn't load the entire file in memory and THEN write it to disk, it writes portions of it as they come. Are you sure about that? It would make sense.

Comment: I assume thats how it works, because there is no way other then that that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

When a file is uploaded via a POST, it is written to a temporary directory on the server, which can then be moved via a PHP function call ([move_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)).

Comment: I know that, it's not what I asked though.